# javac creates an unexpected directory for compiled classes

Tags: java, javac

The case is like this - I have a folder, say ass1, in which I have the src folder with the .java files and an empty bin folder. I then use the following command:

```
javac -cp src -d bin src/*
```

to compile all (there are 3) of the .java files. The files are compiled and work...

but, instead of placing them in the bin folder, the compiler creates an unnecessary ass1 folder in the bin folder and puts the .class files there.

Why? What could be causing this and how do I resolve it?

Lutz, you're a hero. Thanks.

Comment: What are the `package`s of your classes?

Comment: Drat, I knew I would forget to remove that line from the files. Wrote the code in Eclipse for easy testing and bugfixing and forgot to remove the package line from the top. Thanks man!

Comment: Don't remove the `package` declaration. It is bad practice to put a class in the default package (= no `package`).

Comment: Don't really need it though - it's a small exercise for class. Unless it's a really good habit to get into?

Comment: Yes, it is a *very* good habit. Stick to it.

Comment: Okies, will make changes to the makefile then.

Comment: Are you building a Java project with Make?

Answer (score 2):

A class with

```
package ass1;
```

must be in the folder

```
src/ass1
```

`javac` will but the `.class` file in

```
bin/ass1
```

because the package structure must be the same as in `src`.